# Labeling Dates In gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

Let's say we have the following dataframe:

```
> df
  date number
1   9/1      1
2   9/2      2
3   9/3      3
4   9/4      4
5   9/5      5
```

, where the 'date' column has a "month/date" format.

Based on this data, I want to make an animation which has the same "month/date" format in the 'date' column in the x-axis.

However, R throws out an error message that the 'date' column must be a finite number. So I removed '/' in the 'date' column and it now works (see attached
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXtD9.png)) with the following code:

```
df <- data.frame("date" = c(91, 92, 93, 94, 95), "number" = c(1,2,3,4,5))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = number, group =1)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  transition_reveal(date)
p
```

However, how do I label the 'date' column in the x-axis of the animation such that it maintains the "month/date" format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ggplot can handle dates, but they have to be of type date. Otherwise, ggplot can't know how to display them correctly. As far as I know, there is no method for having a date without Year. However, if your data consists of less than a year ggplot won't display the year but only month and day. Here is an example:

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(gganimate)
    library(gifski)

    df <- data.frame("date" = c(91, 92, 93, 94, 95), "number" = c(1,2,3,4,5))

    df$date <- as.Date(c("2019-09-01", "2019-09-02", "2019-09-03", "2019-09-04", "2019-09-05"))

    p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = number, group =1)) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_point() +
      transition_reveal(date)
    p
```